vertical alignment of a tkzpicture in a longtable cell
I am struggling to get a tkzpicture vertical center or top aligned in a longtable cell with the text. Somehow it aligns on the bottom baseline:

I am trying to get them to all top align.
Simplified example below.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

% define a square with text
\def\sqs{2.6cm}
\newcommand{\square}[3]{\node[inner sep=5pt, outer sep=5pt, minimum height=\sqs,minimum width=\sqs,fill=#3,draw,label={[align=center]center:#2}] at (#1){};}

\newcommand{\someset}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \square{0,3}{A}{#1};
        \square{3,3}{B}{#2};
        \square{0,0}{C}{#3};
        \square{3,0}{D}{#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% Smaller version to use in tables.
\newcommand{\smallset}[4]{\resizebox{2.3cm}{1cm}{\someset{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}

\begin{longtable}[t]{|p{2cm}||p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline 
foo & \smallset{red}{green}{green}{red} & some long text that will be on many lines and so on some long text that will be on many lines and so on  \\
\hline
foo & \smallset{red}{green}{green}{red} & boo \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}

Setting baseline=(current bounding box.center) to baseline=(current bounding box.north) yields a division by zero. Setting it to center does not seem to center it with the text.
The desired output is both text and tkzpicture all top aligned.

Have a look at the adjustbox package

(... and more precisely, at the valign option)

The main problem is that \resizebox scales the height, not the total height (height plus depth).  If you align the top, it reduces the; height and scales too much.

This places the baseline corectly for both \someset and \smallset.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

% define a square with text
\def\sqs{2.6cm}
\newcommand{\square}[3]{\node[inner sep=5pt, outer sep=5pt, minimum height=\sqs,minimum width=\sqs,fill=#3,draw,label={[align=center]center:#2}] at (#1){};}

\newcommand{\someset}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(BASE)]
        \square{0,3}{A}{#1};
        \square{3,3}{B}{#2};
        \square{0,0}{C}{#3};
        \square{3,0}{D}{#4};
      \path (current bounding box.north) ++(0pt,-\ht\strutbox) coordinate (BASE);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% Smaller version to use in tables.
\newcommand{\smallset}[4]{\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}% set baseline
  {\resizebox{2.3cm}{2cm}%
    {\raisebox{\depth}% make height total height
      {\someset{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}}}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}||p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline 
foo & \smallset{red}{green}{green}{red} & some long text that will be on many lines and so on some long text that will be on many lines and so on  \\
\hline
foo & \smallset{red}{green}{green}{red} & boo \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}


Excelent. Thanks - and anchoring it like this also solves an other class of puzzles was having.
